# Link Spacing Issue in CSS

Tags: jquery, button, hover

Basically what this is a menu, on hover, a separate image will appear on both sides on the link. I got this far however I can't seem to get rid of the white spacing on the link. There should be no white space above the link on hover. Can't seem to figure out what I'm missing!?

```
<li><a href="#" class="button">Button 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="button">Button 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="button">Button 3</a></li>    

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").hover(function() {
        $(this).before('<div class="buttonimgleft"></div>');
        $(this).after('<div class="buttonimgright"></div>');
                }, function() {
        $(".buttonimgleft, .buttonimgright").remove();
    });
});


body { 
    margin: 0;
}

li { 
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.buttonimgright { 
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CC0000 url('insert-right-image.png');
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
}

.buttonimgleft { 
    display: inline-block; 
    background: #CC0000 url('insert-left-image.png');
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
} 

a { 
    height: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background: #CC0000;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEXG3/1/

Comment: A bit of unsolicited advice: the idea of CSS is to share rule and modify only the exceptions. You have elements with the display, width and height the same; they can share the same rule instead of being redeclared. :)

Comment: They don't share the same background image though. Suggestions?

Comment: Not saying this is perfect, but here's the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/vEXG3/8/ It's fewer characters by a bit, but more importantly you can make changes in one rule instead of three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;` to your links and image divs.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vEXG3/4/)**

```
.buttonimgright {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CC0000 url('insert-right-image.png');
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.buttonimgleft {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #CC0000 url('insert-left-image.png');
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
a {
    height: 20px;
    color: #000;
    background: #CC0000;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Solved! This works. All I had to do was add display: inline-block to the link element and it works as I wanted to. Thanks for everyones input here! Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vEXG3/6/

Comment: So, basically, you followed the directions in my answer but accepted this one? (No, I'm not bitter, just confused.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the style `vertical-align: middle;` (`bottom` works too) to both `.buttonimgright` and `buttonimgleft`.

Furthermore, you should add the style `display: inline-block;` to the `a` tag, since you can't set a height on `inline` elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/vEXG3/5/

Comment: Thanks but there's still some white space left. Do you know how I can totally get rid of it so that the left/right images line up seamlessly?

Comment: Follow the instructions in my second paragraph and make sure all three elements have the same height.